# Is HTTP Content-Length Header Safe to Trust?

Tags: http, http-headers, httprequest

Is it safe to trust the `Content-Length` HTTP header? According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length) it is a `Forbidden header name`. If I go to [that page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) it says the following.

> Modifying such headers is forbidden because the user agent retains full control over them.

But wouldn't there still be a way to spoof these values if you control the user agent?

I'm just trying to figure out how safe it is to trust those headers on that  [`Forbidden header name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name) page and if they are able to be spoofed at all.

Comment: Trust for what, spoofed by whom? What's the scenario you're worried about?

Comment: @Joni Trusted that it is accurate and follows the spec. For example I don't want a request to come in that in reality has a real content length of 1000 say, and the header Content-Length of 300 for example. In this scenario it would be spoofed by the client or whoever is making the request to my backend.

Answer (score 5):

Given the scenario you describe, yes it's possible for a client to set the incorrect Content-Length. There is no guarantee that it's correct.

If `Content-Length` is too large, a server might wait and time-out to get the remainder of the data. If it's too small, the server might cut the TCP connection before the entire body came in, or in the case of `Connection: Keep-Alive` the server might assume the client started another HTTP request, get confused and send a bad request response.

Comment: Isn't it the reverse ?